# Where can I ask about a game engine's general patterns?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

Note: If this is wrong Stack Exchange section to post in, I apologize. If so, where should I post the questions covering the topic below?

I am wondering if this is appropriate to ask in Stack Exchange’s “[Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tour)” section or “[Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour)” section or another section. At this time, I do not have enough points to ask in their chat rooms nor their meta sections. I am asking because I am new to Stack Exchange's point system and do not want to accumulate negative points.

Previously, I tried asking in Stack Exchange's "[Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour)" section, but that does not seem to be the correct section.

Specifically, I want to ask a question about a specific type of coding upkeep when using [game engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_engine) X (and I will use game engine X's real name when I post the question once I in the right section).

I am not asking about a specific coding addition/deletion/change when performing upkeep. I am asking about the general pattern of upkeep.

I hope this doesn’t delve into opinion because this is about a general pattern rather than a specific issue.

Which section should I ask this type of question in?

---

The question:

> What is the typical upkeep of a project made in [Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)), specifically how often/how much code needs to be updated/changed/added when a new Unity version is released and/or when your currently used Unity version becomes deprecated?
>
> I am not asking about a specific coding change. I am asking about the general pattern of upkeep needed whenever I need to switch Unity versions.

Comment: what is "coding upkeep"?

Comment: It might be better to use a more concrete question (like put what you'd ask in your question here in your Meta question), and we could point you to a suitable spot.

Comment: @RobertLongson Sometimes, when a game engine releases a new version, they change how some of their programming words and/or tools work, requiring users to either change the words in their program to align with the new update and/or learn how to use/integrate the new tool. Sometimes, this involves disconnecting from an old tool and replacing it with the new tool

Comment: Thank you, @Makoto. Should I edit this question or post a new one? Thank you both for your clarifying questions.

Comment: Edit this one.  No need to post a new one, you've got a question here.  Just include it after the initial part of this, separated by three dashes or something.

Comment: "coding upkeep" may be another word for the more standard [software maintenance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_maintenance).

Comment: Such broad survey questions are probably better suited for other types of sites, like a traditional forum or Quora. Example from the latter: *[What is typically involved in web application maintenance?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-typically-involved-in-web-application-maintenance?q=What%20is%20typically%20involved%20in%20web%20application%20maintenance%3F)*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### I suggest asking this over at [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Your question seems to concern the following three [on-topic](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) aspects of game development:

> - **asset pipelines** (creation, storage, editing, etc)
> - game-specific programming issues (**engine architecture**, **game-related APIs**, networking, **tools**, etc.), including modding existing games
> - **project management** (testing, team management, scheduling, publishing, etc.)

The amount of upkeep you are referring to is unique for Unity, software intended for game development, and something most Unity developers will likely be aware of (or the frustration, at least, of having an update break stuff). And even though most answers will likely involve personal experience, your question is definitely not opinion-based, as I’m sure you're hoping for an objective answer.

The only possible reason I can imagine for this being unanswerable, and therefore not entirely welcome, is that it is (presumably) about future updates—but that can be circumvented by taking it into account when writing your question, and asking for an average assessment of the efforts involved.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful, especially the suggestions on how to improve the question!

Comment: That question is probably way too broad. Most questions on Game Development are much more specific and most include actual code or other specific data. On [the Software Recommendations one](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/84549/after-each-new-unity-version-how-often-do-you-need-to-change-your-code), it said *"Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer."*.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum That makes sense, but can you indicate what would make it more precise? Is it about the type of coding that might require updating, the tools used, the scope of the project, ..?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum Hopefully, this isn't too broad a question, but if it is, thanks for your alternative link to Quora. I'm trying to make this an objective question, but since it's a broad question, it might be hard to limit it to something quantifiable.